# ChangeSiteMasterPage for a subiste

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

Is there a way to access the ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx page for a SharePoint 2013 subsite other than directly writing the URL : /_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That page is only for sites using the Publishing Feature. When that feature is enabled, you will find a Master Page link in Site Settings:

[image]